# Read excel and Assign cell Value by column to an array

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Using apache.poi, I am trying to read an Excel sheet and using the below code, I am printing all the values inside Excel..

```
  for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++) {
        Row row = searcsheet.getRow(i);

        // Create a loop to print cell values in a row
        for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            // Print Excel data in console
            String location = (row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+ "");
            System.out.println(location);
        }
```

When I print the location `System.out.println(location);`, it prints my all Excel sheet data. I haven't any control over there. I am trying divide the value by the column.

Suppose I have 3 cells and I want to get a value like `firstname[],lastname[],age[]` so that I can do any operation by the indexing. I am not getting any solution.

[image]

Here is my full code
https://codeshare.io/anNwy3

Comment: Maybe you can read it into a 2D array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a 2D String array. When iterating store the contents into the array

```
String[][] excelData = new String[numColumns][searcsheet.getLastRowNum()];
//numColumns is the number of columns in the excel sheet.
for (int i = 0; i < rowCount + 1; i++) {
    Row row = searcsheet.getRow(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
        String data = (row.getCell(j).getStringCellValue()+ "");
        excelData[j][i] = data;
    }
}
```

This transpose data when storing it into the array (note: `excelData[j][i]` and not `excelData[i][j]`).

With this, you can get all the contents of the first column as `excelData[0]`.

Comment: Great my Friend its work perfectly for me.Thank you so much